# Can't uninstall KDE plasma environment from Centos 7

Tags: centos, gnome, kde, desktop-environment

I recently tried to switch my desktop environment back over to KDE plasma after using XFCE and gnome for a while.  Previously it worked.  Today it decided to just hang on the loading/login screen, but still allowed me to interact with the mouse and power button to log off/restart.  Cool, I didn't want to deal with this today.  Gnome has a bunch of bugs with OpenGL, so I had to move back to KDE to avoid Gnome freezing my system because my GPU was doing actual work (it basically spams the system with a timeout message until it freezes at the slightest hitch in OpenGL, AFAIK the gnome team denied this issue until a bunch of CS:GO players started complaining).

I decided I was just going to wipe KDE plasma off the map, and uninstall/reinstall it.  I thought that all I needed to do was use "groups remove", and indeed, when I type "yum group list" I get

```
Installed Environment Groups:
   GNOME Desktop
   KDE Plasma Workspaces
```

So I figured I could just remove it this way:

```
sudo yum groups remove "KDE Plasma Workspaces"
```

Nope.

```
No group named KDE Plasma Workspaces exists
Maybe run: yum groups mark remove (see man yum)
No packages to remove from groups
```

But this is a lie, I literally just saw the group listed... as installed...

So I decided to double check and make sure I had the desktop environment installed:

```
ls -l /usr/share/xsessions/
total 40
-rw-r--r--. 1 root root 4882 Mar 31 21:59 1-kde-plasma-standard.desktop
-rw-r--r--. 1 root root 7358 Mar 31 21:59 2-kde-plasma-safe.desktop
-rw-r--r--. 1 root root 7678 Mar 31 21:49 gnome-classic.desktop
-rw-r--r--. 1 root root 7544 Aug  8  2019 gnome.desktop
-rw-r--r--. 1 root root 5465 Apr 15  2016 xfce.desktop
```

Yep.

How do I actually reinstall KDE plasma on my system?

Comment: How about `yum groups mark install "KDE Plasma Workspaces"` and then remove it?

Comment: @Krackout Same error "No group named "KDE Plasma Workspaces"" exists. I'm starting to wonder if KDE Plasma Workspaces isn't the right name, and somehow it got marked a long time ago.